# ifconfig netmask ip alternative

Tags: networking, ip, command, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ifconfig

What is the `ifconfig netmask` command `ip` alternative for this command:

```
ifconfig eth0 netmask 255.255.240.0
```

I found something like this, but honestly I'm not sure, since the address is missing:

```
ip addr add broadcast dev eth0
```

**EDIT:**

To be more precise, I want to fix my WSL 2 on Windows, because currently I can't access to internet from WSL2. I found this possible solution, ([github issue link](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4275#issuecomment-511578223)) but it uses `ifconfig` and it's not part of the `Ubuntu 20.04` and since I can't connect to internet, I can't download the `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of setting a network mask without an IP is a strange one.  The ifconfig utility appears to have been written to assume there will be only one IP address.  Interfaces can have many IP addresses and the network mask is always associated with an IP address.

Your question doesn't indicate whether or not the interface already has an ip address.  But the "equivalent" is to add an IP address with the required netmask:

```
ip addr add 10.10.10.20/20 dev eth0
```

If the IP address already exists you may need to remove it first with `ip addr del ...`.  Eg if the IP you want to set already has network mask 255.255.255.0:

```
ip addr del 10.10.10.20/24 dev eth0
ip addr add 10.10.10.20/20 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you have the device you want with:

```
ip a show
```

From there you can just set an `ip` and mask:

```
sudo ip a add 192.168.0.1/255.255.240.0 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

`ip addr add 192.168.0.1/20 dev eth0`

Still requires you to specify the host IP address, so there's no direct alternative.