# How do you change the netmask?

Tags: network-interface, ip

Is there a command that would let me change the netmask of an IP assigned to an interface ?

example :

```
$ ip a show eth4
2: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:8e:38:99:f7:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.211.70/**24** brd 192.168.211.255 scope global eth4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f68e:38ff:fe99:f781/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip <some> <magic> <command> dev eth4
$ ip a show eth4
2: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:8e:38:99:f7:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.211.70/**16** brd 192.168.211.255 scope global eth4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f68e:38ff:fe99:f781/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$
```

Or is deleting / reassigning the IP the only way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ifconfig eth4 netmask 255.255.0.0
```

This will change your netmask for device eth4 from /24 to /16. The change is only temporary though and should be done permanently in your network setup.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That command isn't available on modern linuces. They advocated years ago to transition to `ip`, which I never did, until `ifconfig` and `route` disappeared... So now I'm forced to learn my way through `ip`.

Comment: Searching for an equivalent, I found that it is not available https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595214/ifconfig-netmask-ip-alternative.

Comment: The top answer at that post suggests to delete and recreate via ip:
    ip addr del 192.168.211.70/24 dev eth4
    ip addr add 192.168.211.70/16 dev eth4

Comment: Thanks @Uwe, as mentioned in my question it seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

A NIC can have more than one address, so the netmask can only be set when setting the IP address. the `ifconfig` command equivalent only works because it assumes NICs have only one address. There is no way to change only the netmask with the `ip` tool.